# I keep getting a SIGABRT error when programming making a draggable label?

Tags: xcode, swift, swift2, uilabel, viewcontroller

I am trying to make a Draggable label programmatically, I can get the Label to appear but as soon as I try to drag it I throw the error. Any suggestions? There is absolutely nothing else on the screen. it is an empty View controller to start with.

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.width / 2 - 100 , self.view.bounds.height / 2 - 50, 200, 100))
    label.text = "Drag Me!"
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    self.view.addSubview(label)

    let gesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("Was Dragged:"))
    label.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
    label.userInteractionEnabled = true
}
```

Comment: What exception does it throw ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use a space in the selector name. And did you create the function with the name of the selector ?

Try this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.width / 2 - 100 , self.view.bounds.height / 2 - 50, 200, 100))
    label.text = "Drag Me!"
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    self.view.addSubview(label)

    let gesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("wasDragged"))
    label.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
    label.userInteractionEnabled = true
}

func wasDragged() {
    print("i've been dragged")
}
```

Comment: I had the func  but the space and a capitalization was the mistake, man i feel stupid! Thanks again!!!

Comment: Don't worry it happens ;)